# What is an expanded JDK?

Tags: java, apache, netbeans

In the coming version of Apache Netbeans, there's a new feature that looks impressive but I don't understand what it's all about.

https://github.com/apache/incubator-netbeans/pull/918

What is an expanded JDK? How can it be useful?

Comment: Java 9+ is modular. [Understanding Java 9 Modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html).

Comment: I understand that Java 9+ is modular and that you must declare which modules your app will use from the standard JDK and 3rd-party libraries but I still don't understand what is an expanded JDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Expanded** must be a synonym for **exploded**. This is hinted by the fact that this pull request is about using freshly compiled JDKs.

So, what is an exploded JDK then? This is explained at https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/doc/building.md#running-make:

> [An exploded JDK] is a minimal (or roughly minimal) set of compiled
>   output needed for a developer to
>   actually execute the newly built JDK. The idea is that in an
>   incremental development fashion, when doing a normal make, you should
>   only spend time recompiling what's changed (making it purely
>   incremental) and only do the work that's needed to actually run and
>   test your code.

The easy guess is that the terms *expanded* and *exploded* are used because, in this case, the modules are still available as a raw set of folders and class files instead of neatly compressed unique files. This last stage of neat packaging is a waste of time when you continually modify the JDK itself. So, it's skipped over while testing the JDK.